# stop form to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, java, forms, servlets

So I got a hidden form. Basically, when I press a button `btnInsert` I want to submit the hidden form to java servlet and submit the data inside form to database without refreshing the page. So inside `btnInsert` function I have writen something like `myForm.submit()` but I have no idea how to prevent it from refreshing, I tried using `e.preventDefault()` but it is not working for me. Below is my sample code

```
function sentRequest(a,b,c,d){
console.log(a,b,c,d)
var form = document.getElementById("forminput")
var btnform = document.getElementById("btnform")
form.submit()
```

thank you for any advice!

Comment: Form submit will always refresh once it has a response from the server, make an ajax/fetch call instead of doing form.submit()

Comment: If you don't want to refresh your page you should use Ajax to send information to the server.

Comment: thank you guys! its working for me after i use ajax

Answer (score 1):

Form submissions **always** refresh the page, thats simply how they work.

If you dont want this to happen you should make an AJAX call (asynchronous javascript and XML).

You can make a Get request using the `fetch()` function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

or by making use of the XMLHttpRequest object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Alternativly if you could make use of a library named AxiosJS that handles all this stuff for you (https://github.com/axios/axios)